# Pure JavaScript or jQuery file download function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using Javascript, I'm trying to establish an appropriate method to display a PDF file in a new browser tab. If the browser doesn't have an in-built PDF viewer, I'd like the user to have the option to download the file. My research has led me to John Culviner's jQuery plugin ***jquery.fileDownload.js*** [here](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-v1-4-0-released-with-promise-support/), and that looks a great fit. The issue I have however is that I don't have access to the web server hosting the site in order to upload the plugin. I've also been unable to find a CDN that hosts the plugin and which I could link to.

Does anyone have a few 'best practice' suggestions to achieve my goals that I can research further? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to involve JS. Just link to the PDF. Use the `target` attribute to trigger a new tab.

```
<a href="foo.pdf" target="_blank">
```

If the server lies about the content-type of the PDF or sends a header that indicates it should be downloaded instead of rendered, then you are out of luck.

If you *really* want to use JS, then:

```
window.open('foo.pdf');
```

Comment: Thanks David, I'll try both approaches and see whether the server throws a spanner in the works.